# "По части" или "в части"

Tags: морфология

> "ответственны руководители подразделений, директора учреждений и предприятий *(каждый в своей части / каждый по своей части)"*

Как правильнее: "в своей части" или "по своей части"?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

> каждый **по** своей части.

Смотрите [тут](https://phraseology.academic.ru/13818/%D0%9F%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).